# Проблемы в коде 1С "обработка проведения"

Tags: 1с

Почему-то не задействована часть кода, (как узнал, через отладчик) Код Обрывается на

> **Пока ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Следующий() Цикл**

Вот код, эта часть кода находится в самом конце
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Процедура ОбработкаПроведения(Отказ, Режим)
    //{{__КОНСТРУКТОР_ДВИЖЕНИЙ_РЕГИСТРОВ

// регистр Взаиморасчеты Приход
    Движения.Взаиморасчеты.Записывать = Истина;
    Движение = Движения.Взаиморасчеты.Добавить();
    Движение.ВидДвижения = ВидДвиженияНакопления.Приход;
    Движение.Период = Дата;
    Движение.Контрагент = Клиент;
    Движение.Сумма = СуммаДокумента;

    // регистр Продажи 
    Движения.Продажи.Записывать = Истина;
    Для Каждого ТекСтрокаТовары Из Товары Цикл
        Движение = Движения.Продажи.Добавить();
        Движение.Период = Дата;
        Движение.Клиент = Клиент;
        Движение.Номенклатура = ТекСтрокаТовары.Товар;
        Движение.Количество = ТекСтрокаТовары.Количество;
        Движение.Сумма = ТекСтрокаТовары.Сумма;
    КонецЦикла;

    // регистр ТоварыНаСкладах Расход
    Движения.ТоварыНаСкладах.Записывать = Истина;
    Для Каждого ТекСтрокаТовары Из Товары Цикл
        Движение = Движения.ТоварыНаСкладах.Добавить();
        Движение.ВидДвижения = ВидДвиженияНакопления.Расход;
        Движение.Период = Дата;
        Движение.Номенклатура = ТекСтрокаТовары.Товар;
        Движение.Склад = Склад;
        Движение.Количество = ТекСтрокаТовары.Количество;
    КонецЦикла;

    Движения.Записать();

    Если Режим = РежимПроведенияДокумента.Оперативный Тогда
    КонецЕсли;
    Запрос = Новый Запрос;
    Запрос.Текст = 
    "ВЫБРАТЬ
    |   ТоварыНаСкладахОстатки.Номенклатура КАК Номенклатура,
    |   ТоварыНаСкладахОстатки.Склад КАК Склад,
    |   -ТоварыНаСкладахОстатки.КоличествоОстаток КАК Количество
    |ИЗ
    |   РегистрНакопления.ТоварыНаСкладах.Остатки(
    |           ,
    |           Склад = &Склад
    |               И Номенклатура В
    |                   (ВЫБРАТЬ
    |                       РеализацияТоваровИУслугТовары.Товар КАК Товар
    |                   ИЗ
    |                       Документ.РеализацияТоваровИУслуг.Товары КАК РеализацияТоваровИУслугТовары
    |                   ГДЕ
    |                       РеализацияТоваровИУслугТовары.Ссылка = &Ссылка)) КАК ТоварыНаСкладахОстатки
    |ГДЕ
    |   ТоварыНаСкладахОстатки.КоличествоОстаток < 0";

    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Склад", Склад);
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Ссылка", Ссылка);

    РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();
    Если НЕ РезультатЗапроса.Пустой() Тогда
        Отказ = Истина;

    ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();

    Пока ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Следующий() Цикл
        // Вставить обработку выборки ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи
        Сообщить("Недостаточно товара"+ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Номенклатура+"в колличестве"+ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Количество);
    КонецЦикла;
КонецЕсли;
Если НЕ Отказ Тогда

    Движения.СебестоимостьТоваров.Записывать = Истина;


    Запрос = Новый Запрос;
    Запрос.Текст = 
    "ВЫБРАТЬ
    |   СебестоимостьТоваровОстатки.Номенклатура КАК Номенклатура,
    |   СебестоимостьТоваровОстатки.СуммаОстаток КАК Сумма,
    |   СебестоимостьТоваровОстатки.КоличествоОстаток КАК Количество
    |ИЗ
    |   РегистрНакопления.СебестоимостьТоваров.Остатки(
    |           &МоментВремени,
    |           Номенклатура В
    |               (ВЫБРАТЬ
    |                   РеализацияТоваровИУслугТовары.Товар КАК Товар
    |               ИЗ
    |                   Документ.РеализацияТоваровИУслуг.Товары КАК РеализацияТоваровИУслугТовары
    |               ГДЕ
    |                   РеализацияТоваровИУслугТовары.Ссылка = &Ссылка)) КАК СебестоимостьТоваровОстатки";

    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("МоментВремени", МоментВремени());
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Ссылка", Ссылка);

    РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();

    ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();

    Пока ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Следующий() Цикл
        Если ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Количество <> 0 Тогда
        СебестоимостьЕдиницы = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Сумма/ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Количество;
    Иначе 
        СебестоимостьЕдиницы = 0;
    КонецЕсли;

        Движение = Движения.СебестоимостьТоваров.Добавить();
        Движение.ВидДвижения = ВидДвиженияНакопления.Расход;
        Движение.Период = Дата;

        СтрокаТЧ = Товары.Найти(ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Номенклатура, "Товар");

        Движение.Номенклатура = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Номенклатура;
        Движение.Количество = СтрокаТЧ.Количество;
        Движение.Сумма = СебестоимостьЕдиницы * СтрокаТЧ.Количество;
    КонецЦикла;


КонецЕсли;

КонецПроцедуры
```

Answer (score 0):

Если прерывается с ошибкой, то проблема в коде.
Если не заходит внутрь цикла, значит запрос вернул пустой ответ. 
В регистре накопления "СебестоимостьТоваровОстатки" по номенклатуре из данного документа нет записей.
Можно скачать консоль запросов или встроенной в 1С воспользоваться, и запустить этот запрос в режиме предприятия. Тогда можно будет понять, что не так.

Answer (score 0):

Первое: Вы неправильно проверяете остатки, поэтому в отказ не уходит. Нужно соединять существующую номенклатуру с записями в регистре, т.к. записей может не быть, а остаток нужно контролировать в любом случае
Второе: запрос возвращает пустые значения. Значит в регистре "Себестоимость" нет записей. Такого быть не может, если вы прошли контроль остаток. А это произошло, потому что вы неправильно проверяете остатки.

Таблица товаров должна быть слева, а "КоличествоОстаток" - справа и обязательна проверка на ISNULL. В таком случае у вас проведение уйдёт в отказ и до себестоимости не дойдет. Как только сделаете поступление и будут записи в обоих регистрах, то всё будет хорошо